# ASP.Net re-direct from URL after authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config

I have a web app where user is required to authenticate to view certain pages.

Authentication is forced in web.config by doing a re-direct to Login.aspx

When user is on the Login.aspx page the URL is in the following format:

http://localhost:51101/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSupport.aspx

After user authorizes I'd expect ASP.Net to re-direct the user to Support.aspx page, but this doesn't happen.

Support.aspx is not the only page that requires authentication, therefore I can't do a re-direct in a code-behind file.

Is there a web.config setting that I'm missing out?

Thank you

**Edit:**

Basic authentication logic

```
            if (!Membership.ValidateUser(user, password))
            {
                errorId.Text = "Incorrect username or password";
            }
            else
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, true);  
                // I can add a re-direct here, but it won't do the job since there are multiple pages that require authentication
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps the login page is also responsible for logging the user out and is doing so just after the user logs in.

Comment: So where do they get redirected upon successful login?

Comment: Does login.aspx have any code? If so, please show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Forms Authentication?  If so, you will need to call the

```cs
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()
```

method in Login.aspx

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to have ASP.NET to handle that for you. You might have to look for "returnUrl" in the querystring manually in Global.asax Session_Start() and redirect to the value if the user is logged in.

Edit: I'm wrong. Thanks to John Pick for correcting me.

Comment: Normally ASP.NET does handle the ReturnUrl automatically.

Comment: Correction: Normally <asp:Login> handles ReturnUrl automatically. The current issue doesn't involve <asp:Login>.